# Trying to access Django REST API in Angular2

Tags: django, angular, get, django-rest-framework

I am working on a project where we use Angular2 and a Django backend that has a rest API. Right now we are simply just trying to get the django backend to send JSON objects to Angular2. For some reason when we make get requests, it comes back as blank. Right now we just have dummy test functions, but even those don't work.

/_services/user.service.ts

```
tempFunc() {
    return this.http.get('http://localhost:8000/chains/', this.jwt()).map((model: Response) => model.json());
}
```

/temptemp-page.component.ts

```
import { Router } from '@angular/router';

import { UserService } from '../_services/user.service';

export class Temp {
  name : string;  
  description : string;
  slogan : string;
  founded_date : string;
  website : string;
}


@Component({
  selector: 'app-temp-page',
  templateUrl: './temp-page.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./temp-page.component.css']
})
export class TempPageComponent implements OnInit {
  model: Temp;


  constructor(
        private router: Router,
        private userService: UserService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
        this.model = {
          name: 'Wrong',
          description: 'Wrong', 
          slogan: 'Wrong', 
          founded_date: 'Wrong', 
          website: 'Wrong',  
        }

    this.userService.tempFunc().subscribe(model => this.model = model);
    console.log(this.model);
  }

}
```

The Wrong is there just to know that if we get nothing, it will print Wrong and we know the get request isn't succeeding.

temp-page-componenent.html

```
 <div style="margin-left: 20px;">
     name: {{ this.model.name }} <br/>
     description: {{ this.model.description }} <br/>
     slogan: {{ this.model.slogan }} <br/>
     founded_date: {{ this.model.founded_date }} <br/>
     website: {{ this.model.website }} <br/>
     <hr/>
 </div>
```

The django backend has a model with field of the type above in this html file, in a table called Chains. at that URL specified. For some reason, every attempt to call it works. Except for Angular2, and I am asking this to figure out if there is just bad syntax, or something else related to the problem. I know it works because when I do

```
curl -g localhost:8000/chains/
```

It works fine and returns

```
[{"name":"Cafe Amazing","description":"Founded to serve the best sandwiches.","slogan":"The best cafe in the Mississippi!","founded_date":"2014-12-04T20:55:17Z","website":"http://www.thecafeamazing.com"}]
```

with a sucess code on the django server of 200 204.

However when I try the angular2 code above it returns the same codes but nothing gets displayed. What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

don't use `this` in your template use only the property name, like this :

```
 <div style="margin-left: 20px;">
     name: {{  model.name }} <br/>
     description: {{ model.description }} <br/>
     slogan: {{  model.slogan }} <br/>
     founded_date: {{  model.founded_date }} <br/>
     website: {{ model.website }} <br/>
     <hr/>
 </div>
```

you `tempFunc` is asynchronous so  `console.log(this.model)` will be executed first :

```
this.userService.tempFunc().subscribe(model => this.model = model);
    console.log(this.model);
```

do this :

```
this.userService
    .tempFunc()
    .subscribe(model =>{ 
         this.model = model
         console.log(this.model);
    });
```

Comment: So the console.log now finally shows it so I know the API is working! Thanks! However the template still wont show them, it's just blank.

Comment: is there any errors in the console? is the template blank do you see `name:` and `description:` and others ?

Comment: I think you have to fix The Jquery error. add jquery library and see.

Comment: are you sure you put `{{  model.name }}` instead of `{{  this.model.name }}` because your code is fine

Comment: Positive. If it helps at all, for a split second when the page loads, it shows "Wrong" in all the fields for like .5 seconds, then it turns blank.

Comment: If tried to change the console log just to test. I changed it to console.log(this.model.name) just to print the name out, and it comes out as undefined. However if I do this.model[0].name it will show the name.